# How to properly format a Copy-Item when filenames and file paths have apostrophes and brackets?

Tags: windows, powershell, copy-item

[I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253900/how-can-i-copy-specific-files-from-a-nas-to-my-pc-with-a-list-of-their-locations) about a litany of MP3 files that are in a Plex playlist which I want to put on my local PC and upload to an MP3 player. While I was able to get some of the basics down, I encountered some issues going forward with all ~850 songs.

After figuring out that tracks with an `&` would throw an error, I enclosed everything in `"xyz"` double quotes.

After running the script:

`Copy-Item -Path "\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\The Wombats\Greek Tragedy\01 Greek Tragedy.mp3", "\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\DJ El-Bravo\Dem Bow Mix Tape Vol. 2\The Way I Are (Chachi Remix).mp3", "\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Whilk and Misky\The First Sip [Single]\Babe I'm Yours.mp3", "\\192.168.14\Synology Media\Music\Big Sean\One Man Can Change The World\One Man Can Change The World.mp3" -Destination C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Copy`

I noticed that I was missing about 100 songs. I determined that it was a result of files that had square brackets, `[` or `]`, as part of their file name or path. To rectify this, I had to enclose those files in single quotes and add a backtick, for example,

`` '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Whilk and Misky\The First Sip `[Single`]\Babe I'm Yours.mp3', ``

However, the issue then became cases like the above example where there is an apostrophe in the path or filename. The `I'm` apostrophe acts as though that `'` is that closing '`' and not just part of the file name. And enclosing it in double quotes will not work.

**Is there a proper way to format this kind of filename structure?**

Here are a few extra examples of files with this issue.

`` '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Imagine Dragons\Continued Silence EP `[Single`]\It's Time.mp3' ``

`"\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Blink 182\Glorious\Adam's Song (Kasum Remix).mp3",`

`` '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Victoria Bigelow\To Everyone I've Loved Before `[Single`]\To Everyone I've Loved Before.mp3', ``

`` '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\The Pharcyde\Sold My Soul The Remix & Rarity Collection `[Disc 2`]\Runnin' (Bit Funk Remix).mp3', ``

Comment: So you want to type 850 song names manually?

Comment: The easy solution would be to not have literals. Does `Copy-Item -Recurse '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\'` not do it? If you must have some "curated" list of names that can't be done automatically, stick them in a text file and read that with `Get-Content` (`Copy-Item -Path (Get-Content myfiles.txt)`).

Comment: I don't want to copy the entire music directory, just the specific files. The MP3 player can only hold 32GB, and my '\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\' library is over 100GB. I have an M3U file with all of them listed and accounted for. So if I instead write the files to a txt, how will I want to call that with Get-Content? Is it like `Get-Content (Copy-Item -Path "\\192.168.1.14\Synology Media\Music\Files.txt") -Destination C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Copy`?

Comment: To robustly process _literal_ file paths (rather than _wildcard_ expressions), use the `-LiteralPath` parameter, not `-Path` - see the linked duplicate. Use double-quoting (`"..."`), so that paths with single quotes (apostrophes, `'`) are handled correctly; if paths happen to contain literal `$` characters, escape them as `\`$`

Comment: Could you use `[regex]::escape()`